# Laravel when using ORDER BY get all the other fields

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table like this

```
company       service      time
ABC           carwash      2:00
ABC           carwash      4:00
ABC           carwash      5:00
ABC           repair       6:00
DEF           repair       8:00
```

So, the company ABC will appear multiple times, with repeated services, but the time field will be different.

When I perform a query

```
 $results = company::query()
->select(company.name, service, time) 
->groupBy(company.name)
->where('service' , '=', 'carwash')
->get();
```

I get one result for the company ABC, with it's service and time. That's what I want. But, I want this result to show other times too. So, my ideal query result will be one result, but I can access all the times, i.e., 2:00, 4:00, 5:00

So, when I use foreach function like this

```
<div class="items>
foreach($results as $items)
$items->time
</div>
```

I want to loop through all the times - 2:00, 4:00, 5:00 and show it in the view, as one result, but it will ideally show all the time with a space.

So, this is the result I want, that's why I am using groupBy

> Company is **ABC**, service is **carwash** and times are **2:00, 4:00, 5:00**

I don't want multiple results like this

> Company is **ABC**, service is **carwash** and times are **2:00**
>
> Company is **ABC**, service is **carwash** and times are **4:00**
>
> Company is **ABC**, service is **carwash** and times are **5:00**

Comment: the problem I found here is that you are using group by company.name so the resulted query will group all the rows of ABC where service=carwash

Comment: Note that SQL does not allow grouping by a single column when there are other non-aggregated columns also present. However MySQL may allow you to do this with the proper settings. In your case doing `select("company.name","service",\DB:raw("GROUP_CONCAT(time)")` might work but is not the best solution. The best solution in laravel is to use eloquent with models and relationships

Comment: I want to search for a service, and get the companies name which have those services. If I use where company.name = 'ABC' it will not give the functionality I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you want in MySQL is:

```
mysql> SELECT company, service, GROUP_CONCAT(time) 
FROM companies GROUP BY company, service;
+---------+---------+--------------------+
| company | service | group_concat(time) |
+---------+---------+--------------------+
| ABC     | carwash | 2:00,4:00,5:00     |
| ABC     | repair  | 6:00               |
| DEF     | repair  | 8:00               |
+---------+---------+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

To do that in Laravel, you need `DB::raw`:

```
$results = Company::select(DB::raw('company.name, service, group_concat(time)'))
->where('service' , '=', 'carwash')
->groupBy('company.name')
->get();
```

You probably want to alias the grouped results so you can access them easily:

```
$results = Company::select(DB::raw('company.name, service, group_concat(time) AS times'))
```

Then you can use `$results->times`.